# What is the "Super key" on a Windows laptop keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

At the bottom of this page https://github.com/Paaskehare/pastebin-sublime-plugin it says

> Select some text (or dont) and hit <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and afterwards <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> - and you're good to go!

What is the <kbd>Super</kbd> key supposed to be?

Answer (score 9):

The Windows key is usually the "Super" key

Answer (score 7):

There is actually a Wikipedia article on the [Super Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)).

As Iain Simpson noted, it's usually the Windows logo key.